# Set anchor with angles in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some circle nodes placed in an equilateral triangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick}]
    \node (A) at (0,1.732) [nodestyle] {A};
    \node (B) at (-1,0) [nodestyle] {B};
    \node (C) at (1,0) [nodestyle] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

now I want something like `\draw [->] (A.south west) -- (B.north east)` but the anchor is not placed at `225deg`/`45deg` but `240deg`/`60deg`

How can I set the degrees of anchors?

Comment: Use A.225 etc. E.g. A.west means A.180 etc.

Comment: @MS-SPO Great Answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you specifing the anchor?
Let TikZ do its work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick}]
    \node (A) at (0,1.732) [nodestyle] {A};
    \node (B) at (-1,0) [nodestyle] {B};
    \node (C) at (1,0) [nodestyle] {C};
    \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]